# Plotting probability of a list of floating point values in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a list `ans` using the following code and have tried to create histogram plots of `ans` using both matplotlib and seaborn using `density=True` but I still don't get a probability density of the list of the values in `ans`. Here is the code.

```
num=100000
ans=[]
T=4.5*math.pi
num_bins=50
for i in range(num):
    val=0.5*np.random.chisquare(1)+np.random.exponential(1)
    q=np.random.randn()
    repeats=int(T/(2*q))
    listofrepeats=list(itertools.repeat(val,repeats))
    for val in listofrepeats:
        ans.append(val)

#plt.hist(ans,bins=num_bins,normed=True)
sns.distplot(ans, hist=True, kde=False, 
             bins=num_bins, color = 'blue',
             hist_kws={'edgecolor':'black'})
x=np.linspace(0.01,20,1000)
y=[0.5*np.exp(-0.5*n) for n in x]
plt.plot(x,y,lw=3,c='r',label='Chi sqrd with df=2')

plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

The density plot I get is [image] and as you can see, the density has large values. I am looking for a plotting tool wherein a probability is calculated for each bin and the probabilities sum to one. Is there such a tool? Thanks.

Comment: Where is  `density=True` in this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normalizing a histogram with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781927/normalizing-a-histogram-with-matplotlib)

Comment: With seaborn you can use `sns.histplot(...., stat='probability')`.  See e.g. [Seaborn Plot Distribution with histogram with stat = density or probability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73872722/seaborn-plot-distribution-with-histogram-with-stat-density-or-probability)

Comment: Note that `stat='density'` means that the total **area** sums to 1, while `stat='probability'` has the **sum of the bar heights** totaling to 1.  Both are equal when all bars would be `1` x unit wide.  To fit a normalized curve, you need density, not probability. So, `plt.hist(..., density=True)` or `sns.histplot(..., stat='density')`

Comment: @JohanC Thank you, that was helpful. If I use `sns.distplot(...,stat='probability')`, then I get an `unexpected keyword argument` error and if I use `sns.histplot(...,stat='probability')` then I get an error: `module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'histplot'`. Any idea how to get around that?

Comment: You need to upgrade to a new seaborn version.  `sns.distplot` is rather old and doesn't work with the latest improvements and extensions.